# JavaEE Filter for the index page

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, url-pattern

I used the following Java EE Filter for some pages:

```xml
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/article/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I deployed my project on a domain, like `www.mydomain.com` and I set as welcome page the file `index.jsp`.

If I visit `www.mydomain.com`, it shows the welcome page, **but the filter doesn't work because it doesn't match with the rule**.

If I visit `www.mydomain.com/index.jsp` , everything is working well.

So, all I want to do is the filter matches when I visit `www.mydomain.com` (because `index.jsp`is being showed).

How could I do it?

---

**Update**: I tried the following pattern, but it didn't work:

```xml
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Not much experience here but if you go to "/" then your servlet is presumably forwarding to the /index.jsp page and by that time it has already gone through the filters. So, why not a "/" url pattern in your filters?

Comment: I tried that with no luck :( Thanks for your try

Comment: @WebFilter("/*")
public class ResponseFilter implements Filter {

Comment: @K.Nicholas the problem of that is that it will match with all the pages I use in my site (every one).

Comment: true. I think if for some reason you want only to filter on the "/" url, and then some other url's but not others you will have to make the homepage an HTML 302 redirect to something like /home and filter on that. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0";url='http://www.yourdomain.com/home">`